# JavaScript : White space adding between two string vriable why not in sequence of two strings

Tags: javascript

1) Using variable:

```
var str1 = "Hi";

var str2 = "Geeks!";

document.write(str1+str2);
```

**OUTPUT:**

Hi Geeks!

---

2) Using Quotes

```
document.write("Hi"+"Geeks!");
```

**OUTPUT**

HiGeeks!

---

But,in a sequence made of strings if I use quotes I don't have any space between concatenation of two strings.. why?
Thanks.

Comment: Where does Hello World come from?

Comment: sorry for that I chage it

Comment: This is not correct, the first code example bhaves exactly the same as the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying that in the following code (1) print

```
Hi Geeks!
```

And (2)

```
HiGeeks!
```

The former with a space and the latter without it? 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6bspLfm/2/)

```
<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var str1 = "Hi";
        var str2 = "Geeks!";

        document.write(str1 + str2); //(1)
        document.write("<br>");
        document.write("Hi" + "Geeks!"); //(2)

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

There is no space between them, if you write this:

```
document.write("Hi" + " Geeks!");
```

or this:

```
document.write("Hi " + "Geeks!");
```

or this:

```
document.write("Hi" + " " + "Geeks!");
```

there is one!

Answer (score 0):

**read the documentation of js**

```
and the str1 + str2 will give you "helloworld"
```

**to concat two strings with space**

```
var str1 = "hello";
var str2 = "world";

console.log(str1 +' '+ str2)
```

**'+'** is used to concat two strings